# Vue js - Retaining data values on form submit

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using laravel with Vuejs.

I am using vuejs to clean values in the form (take out the spaces and uppercase letters).

The problem I am having as when the form is submitted (I want to use Laravel validation) the values seem to reset. Is there a way to retain the data or set the data only on initialisation.

The vuejs

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {Graph},
   data: {
       nice_name:'',
       column_name: '',
  },

  methods: {

    setColumnName: function () {
     this.column_name = this.nice_name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,"_");
    },

  }
});
```

The form element

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nice Name</label>
                    <input class="col-md-12 form-control" type="text" name="nice_name" @keyup="setColumnName" v-model="nice_name" v-bind="nice_name">
                </div>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I have to look over my code it was a while ago but am certain I just wrote a cookie or temporarily stored it in local storage. Then when the page refreshed I put it back in if it existed. Not very elegant.

Comment: can you post your code?